# Consume REST from ruby, is there a good gem for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I need to consume resources from a REST api, and I'm trying to find a good gem for doing this, but I can't find anything good...

What do you use for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [REST Client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) gem for this - it's worked well so far.

Answer (score 2):

I use Active Resource.  (But Active Resource is too short an answer since StackOverflow requires that answers be at least 30 characters.)